# Inner Join, Select SUM and Where

Tags: php, mysql, join, sum

**Hi!! I need to search for the stock.id where the SUM of all pedidos.cantidad is >= than $sale**

I've wrote this, but seems like it's not working:

```
SELECT *
     , SUM(pedidos.cantidad) as total 
  FROM stock 
 INNER 
  JOIN pedidos 
    ON stock.producto = pedidos.producto 
 WHERE pedidos.producto = '$sale' 
   AND total >= stock.cantidad 
 ORDER 
    BY stock.id ASC 
 LIMIT 1
```

My Tables:
stock

ID | Producto | Cantidad

Pedidos

ID | Producto | Lote | Cantidad

stock.producto needs to be = to pedidos.producto AND stock.id = pedidos.lote So I need this: SELECT stock.id WHERE (stock.cantidad -SUM(pedidos.cantidad)) >= $sale AND stock.producto = pedidos.producto AND stock.id = pedidos.lote

Exactly, When I'm registering a new sale, I need to find the stock.id where (stock.cantidad - SUM(pedidos.cantidad)) IS >= $new_sale to put that stock.id into the new input on pedidos.lote

Its kind of difficult for me trying to explain what I need because I speak Spanish, please apologize me for this

Comment: Please edit your question and have a look into [hwo do I ask mysql questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333796/how-do-i-ask-mysql-questions-without-exposing-my-database)

Comment: You've said `stock.id = pedidos.lote` but not included lote in the table. What is lote, how does lote link pedidos and stock when you are already linking on producto?

Comment: stock.id and pedidos.lote are exactly the same, thats how I need to relate those tables to deduce if there's stock available.

Comment: @GuillermoEsquivel I am still very much confused about how your table structure is.. Some example data on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) would be very helpful however I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your table and data structures.. give this a try:

```
SELECT Stock.ID
FROM   Stock
WHERE  Stock.Producto IN ( 
    SELECT  producto
    FROM    pedidos
    GROUP BY producto
    HAVING SUM(pedidos.cantidad) >= 100 // Your sale value
)
```

What this is doing is:
Get all the Producto records that when grouped together have a sum > $sale then look for all the Stock.IDs which have the Producto's found.

EDIT

```
SELECT Stock.ID
FROM   Stock
WHERE  Stock.Producto IN ( 
    SELECT  Stock.ID, SUM(Pedidos.Cantidad)
    FROM    Pedidos
    INNER JOIN Stock ON Stock.ID = Pedidos.Lote
                     AND Stock.Producto = Pedidos.Producto
    GROUP BY Stock.ID, Pedidos.Producto
    HAVING  SUM(Pedidos.Cantidad) > 1000 --Sale Amount
)
```

Comment: Hi! I forgot something:

Comment: @GuillermoEsquivel And... Don't leave me hanging :). What did you forget?

Comment: Sorry!! : forget this:

stock.producto needs to be = to pedidos.producto AND stock.id = pedidos.lote So I need this: SELECT stock.id WHERE SUM(pedidos.cantidad) >= $sale AND stock.producto = pedidos.producto AND stock.id = pedidos.lote Its kind of dificult for me trying to explain what I need because I speak Spanish, please apologyze me for this

Comment: Exactly, When I'm registering a new sale, I need to find the stock.id where stock.cantidad IS >= $new_sale to put that stock.id into the new input on pedidos.lote

Comment: Please try to clarify your question by editing it. There you have more formating possibilities.

Comment: @GuillermoEsquivel Could you use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to create an example of your database? I am struggling to see how Stock.ID relates to another item in the table - feels like poor design but I need to see the table! Also, as Myonara said, put it in your question